# Should we have a [monotonicity] tag?

Tags: discussion, tagging, tag-wikis

I often encounter problems that require proving or finding the conditions for a function or sequence to be increasing, decreasing, or monotonic. For example, I recently asked [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4837178/how-to-prove-that-fx-frac-cot-frac-pix1-cot-frac-pix-cd) about proving that a function is strictly decreasing for $x>2$.

However, when I want to tag these questions on Mathematics Stack Exchange, I am not sure what tag to use. The closest tag I found is [monotone-functions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/monotone-functions), and I didn't find a tag specifically for proving monotonicity, and I realised that there are many question on this site that deal with monotonicity for functions and sequences  .

[monotone-functions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/monotone-functions) has two problems: the first is it doesn’t include questions about proving sequences to be monotone and the second one is that the description is too vague and broad. When I ask a question that is only concerned with monotonicity, this tag doesn’t seem to be what I want.

Is there a better tag for proving monotonicity of functions and sequences? If not, should there be one? I think there should be a tag for this, because there are many questions related to it. There is already a tag for [minima-maxima](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minima-maxima), which is a related topic, so why not a tag for monotonicity?

Comment: @XanderHenderson should I wait for the 2024 tag management?

Comment: I don't think that we need a new tag management thread at the moment, as the current thread only has 20 answers.